# Modifying and Masking Environmental Layers within specific asia area in R

Tags: r, mask, layer, maxent

I am trying to prepare the environmental layers (constrained in specific Asia area) for use in Maxent model. However, I ran into some error messages in the last line:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rworldmap)
library(dismo)
# A specified range of Asia area that suitable for special species
tsta <- read.csv('CM10_Kop_Shp_V1.2/Asiaclip/Asiaclipt.csv',as.is=TRUE)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vIx9MCfJgfbHpINTlyUGZVbXc/view?usp=sharing][1]
tsta <- tsta[,seq(1,4)]
coordinates(tsta) = c("Lon", "Lat")
gridded(tsta) <- TRUE
ra <- raster(tsta)

# a Rasterstack contains global range of 40 bioclim variables
files3 <- list.files(path=paste
                     ("CM10_1975H_Bio_ASCII_V1.2/CM10_1975H_Bio_V1.2"),
                     , pattern='txt',full.names=TRUE )[https://www.climond.org/Core/Authenticated/Data/CM10_V1.2/CM10_Bio_V1.2/CM10_Bio_ASCII_V1.2/CM10_1975H_Bio_ASCII_V1.2.zip][1]

predictors3 <- stack(files3)
asia.predictors3 <- mask(predictors3,ra)
```

> Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent

The details for predictors3 were

```
predictors3
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 857, 2160, 1851120, 40  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -59.16667, 83.66667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       : CM10_1975H_Bio01_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio02_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio03_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio04_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio05_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio06_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio07_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio08_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio09_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio10_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio11_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio12_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio13_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio14_V1.2, CM10_1975H_Bio15_V1.2, ...
```

The details for ra were:

```
ra
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 213, 290, 61770  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
extent      : 97.5, 145.8333, 18.16667, 53.66667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : Location 
values      : 168505, 377653  (min, max)
```

My goal is to prepare a RasterLayer or Rasterstack contains all variables of "predictors3" but limited in the range of "ra". As you can see the extent of ra was included in the extent of predictors3 and their resolutions were identical. How should I fix the error?

Comment: From help page: "The mask can be either another Raster* object of the **same extent** and **resolution**".

Comment: But I still receive the same wrong error above. Different exents between attached x snd mask

Comment: They should be the **same** extent. They currently are not.

Comment: I added following code to identify the extent: bb <- extent(-180, 180, -59.16667, 83.66667)
extent(r) <- bb
ra2 <- setExtent(ra, bb, keepres=TRUE)
asia.predictors3 <- mask(predictors3,ra2)

Comment: but still get the error message:  Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/R_raster_user/2015-12-25_113604_6496_66889.gri)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use extent of `predictors3` to set extent of `ra`. You changed the resolution of `ra`.

Comment: So Which approach should I adopt? resample?

Comment: Crop first, then mask.

Comment: Solved it, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can post an answer to show how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as the origin and resolution of `ra` and `predictors3` are the same, you can use `crop`

```
predictors3 <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-59.16667, ymx=83.66667, res=1/6)
ra <- raster(xmn=97.5, xmx=145.8333, ymn=18.16667, ymx=53.66667, res=1/6)

x <- crop(predictors3, ra)
```

In other cases, you may need to use (`dis`)`aggregate` or `resample`

Answer (score 0):

According to the above suggestions, I crop the the global climate layer "predictors3" to identify the extent of two rasters. Then, mask the latest raster to acquire the targeting variables limited in specific area.

```
asia.predictors <- crop(predictors3,ra)
asia.predictors3 <- mask(asia.predictors,ra)
```